# How to check difference between two time and if it is in same date in angular 2/4? time format like "HH:mm AM"

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I want to check my time period is on the same date or not for a validation

```
let startDate = currentSelection.startTimeHr + ":" + currentSelection.startTimeMin + " " + currentSelection.startTimeAMPM
let endDate = currentSelection.stopTimeHr + ":" + currentSelection.stopTimeMin + " " + currentSelection.stopTimeAMPM
```

startDate = 02:30 AM
endDate = 06:45 PM

It is easy to if can return a true or false boolean value

Comment: So you are only validating from the starting time & the ending time right? so if the startDate < endDate it should be true. By Date here you are meaning the time?

Comment: yes, only time which is mention in the question @Sachi.Dila

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do here is convert the time to a date object and compare it, Hope this helps

```
var d = new Date(),
    s = "02:30 AM",
    parts = s.match(/(\d+)\:(\d+) (\w+)/),
    hours = /am/i.test(parts[3]) ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 12,
    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

d.setHours(hours);
d.setMinutes(minutes);

console.log(d);

var d2 = new Date(),
    s = "06:45 PM",
    parts = s.match(/(\d+)\:(\d+) (\w+)/),
    hours = /am/i.test(parts[3]) ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 12,
    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

d2.setHours(hours);
d2.setMinutes(minutes);

if(d < d2)
    alert('true');
else
    alert('false');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs. IT supports two dates is same day/before or after.

moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-10-20'); // true

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using getTime method from date object.

**See the following example**

```
var end, start;

start = new Date();
// For applying some delay
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  Math.sqrt(i);
}
end = new Date();
console.log('Operation took ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + ' msec');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime